# Why is the only way out of Meta through the browser back button?

Tags: discussion

Whenever I click through to Meta from the sidebar of Answers I can never find a link that will take me back to Answers.  It seems I'm trapped, unless I exercise the browser back button.  It's fine if I've only looked at one or two pages on the Meta site.  But sometimes I'll be drawn further and further, from question to question, for five, ten, maybe more -- at which point it's more annoying.

Am I missing the way home?  (In which case the UX might need to be re-thought), or is there some reason that management likes it that way?  (If so, I'd like to know why?)

Comment: Took me ages to find the link... but most of the bidding about a "better" user-interface have been overheared. @toscho has even made a custo user stylesheet to get rid of it. He's offering it on github (afaik).

Comment: @kaiser what do you propose. I added an image below to illustrate ;)

Comment: What I propose is that in the right hand sidebar, between the section headed 'TAGGED' and the section headed 'RELATED' insert a section headed 'VISIT ANSWERS' to correspond to the structure on the other side.  Principal of least surprise.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood Making the top menu as prominent as it _could_ be. I'd say, it's just a little _too modest_.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the navigation links at the top, there is an entry `main`.  This link will take you back to the *main* Q&A site.

[image: link to main from meta]

Comment: Thank you!  I swore I'd tried every link.  Obviously I missed one.

Comment: Note that when you're on the main site, the link in that same position becomes a link for `meta`.

Comment: Yeah. But the way I get to Meta, is by being enticed across by the right hand sidebar enticing me over.  It just seems odd that the reverse isn't so on this side.  I keep looking there every time, in the vain hope that suddenly things will be laid out according to the rule of 'least surprise'